# How can I find out the exact colour for my car?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

I have a couple of cars with some paint damage. Neither have custom paint jobs. Is there a website where I can find the exactly colour match based on the stock colours for cars based on make, model and year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open the drivers side front door and look at the door jamb area *(it may be in the general area)* you'll notice a plaque that has all the essential information about the vehicle. Below are a few images showing the location and a couple example of what these plaques look like.

### Location

[image]

### Examples

#### HONDA

[image]

#### FORD### *arrow points to paint code*

[image]
<sub>(source: [ford-trucks.com](http://www.ford-trucks.com/forums/picture.php?albumid=7272&pictureid=30796))</sub>

Comment: You sir, may have just saved me a lot of time. I tip my hat to you.

Comment: Cheers. If your vehicle doesn't have one of these plaques for some ridiculous reason then I could run the VIN and let you know.

Comment: I was actually look at the plaque on the weekend to find the correct tire pressure, but I wasn't looking for the colour, it's good to know it's there.

Comment: On some cars the plaque is under the bonnet, either on the slam panel or the bulkhead.